# iptables allow only user connections mysql 3306

Tags: mysql, iptables

Im trying to setup a rule in iptables where I only allow remote connections if the user trying to login into MySQL is "someuser" and reject all other possible remote connections. Locally should allow any users.

Is this possible? if so what would be a good rule for this?

Any comments will be appreciate it.

Comment: BTW, the remote machine constantly changes IP, so I can't just allow incoming connections from a specific IP.

Comment: Have the remote machine use something like dyndns.com, and use the MySQL GRANT syntax using the dyndns.com hostname.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible at the packet level (which is where IPTables operates). However, MySQL will let you GRANT permissions to users connecting FROM a specific host.

Answer (score 1):

Iptables doesn't know anything about remote users.

A couple good alternatives may include:

- Require the user to build a SSH connection or some type of VPN to your network.
- Use something like [port knocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking), to open access through the firewall only for the person able to send the knock.